# How to identify Adobe DTM IP address?

Tags: server, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

My customer wants to know the IP address of Adobe DTM Servers where it actually hosted.I am not understanding how to identify that.
Is there any method to know??

If anybody knows..please let me know.

Thanks, 
Payal

Comment: Are you looking for a way to identify visitor IPs using DTM or the IP of the domain of the actual header file assets.adobedtm.com ?

Comment: Hi @MarkStringham,I am looking for Adobe to get IP address of my Client dtm servers for staging/prod.how i will get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the Akamai servers that Adobe uses to serve DTM from, there is no fixed IP Address. Akamai is a CDN that Adobe uses to serve the DTM Javascript library and assets. As such, depending on your location (and latency), the edge server serving you changes accordingly. As an extension, the IP Address changes as well.

The only way to acquire the list of IP Addresses (if any and if it is possible) is to ask your Adobe Consultant or Client Care for it.